# Showkeys and Unicode-math conflict

Tags: unicode-math, showkeys

I am using `showkeys` and `unicode-math` packages but got the following error

```
! Missing $ inserted.
```

This is a minimal example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{showkeys}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
%\setmathfont{texgyrepagella-math.otf}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\caption{something}\label{fig}
\end{figure}
\ref{fig}
\end{document}
```

Comment: https://github.com/wspr/unicode-math/issues/281

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`showkeys` relies on the fact that `\underbar` can be used also in text, which is not true any more for `\underbar` as redefined by `unicode-math`.

Workaround: save the original meaning of `\underbar` and make `showkeys` use it instead of the redefined `\underbar`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{showkeys,etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\let\latex@underbar\underbar
\patchcmd{\SK@@ref}{\underbar}{\latex@underbar}{}{}
\makeatother

\usepackage{unicode-math}
%\setmathfont{texgyrepagella-math.otf}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\caption{something}\label{fig}
\end{figure}
\ref{fig}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Who's at fault? I point to `showkeys` that uses the undocumented `\underbar` command, which is present in the LaTeX kernel just because it is in Plain and in the olden times users frequently transferred documents from Plain TeX to LaTeX.

Comment: Surely it must be the other guy's fault! (anyway showkeys is older than latex2e:-)